# php - same source code for command line or web with arguments

Tags: php, arguments

If you are calling php page from web, you can give as 
../../somepage.php?myid=1&trackno=2&anotherparam=3
and then you can use $_REQUEST or $_GET to retrieve the information

In command line, you can use 
$options = getopt("a:b:c:"); to get the options that are passed through arguments

How to make sure, same source works either in web or in command line?

Comment: CLI-parameters and HTTP-parameters are _just different_. So you need to take care about this by yourself

Comment: Include an "argument parser" that first decides in what environment it runs, then parses accordingly, finally make the arguments available in the same manner. That way you don't have to bother in your main script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say your requests are like following;

**WEB**: `http://domain.com/somepage.php?myid=1&trackno=2&anotherparam=3`

**CLI**: `php /path/to/this/php/file/somepage.php 1 2 3`

You can use following php code;

```
<?php

if (!empty($_REQUEST)) {
    $myid = $_REQUEST["myid"];
    $trackno = $_REQUEST["trackno"];
    $anotherparam = $_REQUEST["anotherparam"];  
} else if (!empty($argv)) {
    $myid = $argv[1]; 
    $trackno = $argv[2]; 
    $anotherparam = $argv[3];   
} else {
    die("Invalid request!");
}
```

You have already know how to handle web requests, you can refer [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) for more detail about `$argv`. Simply,

`$argv[0]` => scriptname(somepage.php),

`$argv[1]` => first param, ...,

`$argv[n]` => (n-1)th param

**Edit:**

In order to not miss order of commandline arguments, you can use naming conventions like;

```
php somepage.php myid_1 anotherparam_2 trackno_3
```

and you can use following to handle this;

```
foreach ($argv as $k => $v) {
    if ($k == 0) continue;
    $temp = explode("_", $v);
    ${$temp[0]} = $temp[1];
}
```

Simply,

`myid_3` becomes `$myid = 3;`

variable names hidden in the values so you don't need to know about sequences

Comment: Is there a way to do the command line arguments the same way as web interface? Want to make sure the arguments are named.. since I might have the sequence changed or few missing at times.

Comment: @Joel You can use naming conventions on parameter passing. See my updated answer